# Exclude everything from the sonar scan except one of its subdirectories

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Hi I want to exclude sonar scans  everything except a sub directory in Js how can I achieve this

I tried the following but it is excluding everything

sonar.exclusions>**/js/**/*

Comment: It might help if you shared your file structure

Comment: Src/main/webapp/Js , src/main/js/jquery,   I want to exclude Js files but want to scan jquery directory

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one subdirectory scanned, then simply set `sonar.sources` to that path.

Comment: It is like exclude main directory and scan it's sub directory.          Src/main/webapp/Js , src/main/js/jquery, I want to exclude Js files but want to scan jquery directory – Madhumitha 3 mins ago   edit   delete